# Re-order array with regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array and a regex:

```
var array = ['dog and cat', 'cat and dog', 'horse', 'snake is dangerous'];
var regex = /^((dog)?(snake)?(horse)?(cat)?)/g;
//final output:
var array = ['dog and cat', 'snake is dangerous', 'horse', 'cat and dog'];
```

How do I order this array to have the desired effect?

**Edit**:
I've invented a solution:

```
var array = ['dog','cat']; var re-order = [];
i=0;
while(array[i]){
    if(string.test(array[i])){
        re-order[i] = array[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Just one question: why?

Comment: could items have duplicate starting word like `['dog and cat', 'dog and wolf', ...` ?

Comment: What is the desired effect? Is it to sort based on the words in your regex? Why even use a regex?

Comment: to delete an error linked to another feature.

Comment: i can most likely help. however you likely have 2 different problems you are solving. One is ordering and the other is regex matching

Comment: how in your mind did you come to that order at the bottom? Is it based on the order of the regex? if so then you for sure don't want to use regex

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no: ^(dog) is unic.

Comment: @Intervalia the original idea was to use a regex to do 'sort (...' according to the regex content

Comment: A) Why do you need a regex?  B) There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the sorting

Comment: Use an array instead of regex...sort by index of search term in array

Comment: @Lpc_dark 
I just need to be ordered according to the order criterion that they have within the regex, if not useful I can also take it off.

Comment: The reason I thought of a regex is this: I can have many variants of the same phrase: 'dog ...' but never a duplicate that starts in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getSortValue(str) {
  return sortOrder.reduce(
    (val, key, idx) => {
      let temp = str.substr(0,key.length);
      return (temp === key) ? idx+1 : val;
    }, 0
  );
}

function sortMe(a,b) {
  var a1 = getSortValue(a);
  var b1 = getSortValue(b);
  if (a1 < b1) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a1 > b1) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var sortOrder = ['dog','snake','horse','cat'];
var array = ['dog and cat', 'cat and dog', 'horse', 'snake is dangerous', 'dog and bird', 'cat and fish'];
console.log(array);
array.sort(sortMe)
console.log(array);
```

#### Result:

Before:

```
["dog and cat", "cat and dog", "horse", "snake is dangerous", "dog and bird", "cat and fish"]
```

After:

```
["dog and bird", "dog and cat", "snake is dangerous", "horse", "cat and dog", "cat and fish"]
```

The function `getSortValue` converts the string into an index based on the string and the order of preference. Then the function `sortMe` sorts based on those values and, if the values are the same, then it sorts my string comparison.

> This code does not check for whole-words like `dog` vs `dogs` or `dogfood` but those should be handled by the string comparison portion of the `sortMe` function

Comment: Ty for the help

Comment: I wouldn't use this it as is, it has variables that are not passed in and instead relies on them being global. If this is just a fun project. Then you can use this